# Make new scene of selected hierarchy GameObject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, editor, scene

```
  void OnGUI() {

        GUILayout.Label("Hirarchey GameObject to Scene Conversion", EditorStyles.boldLabel);
        gameObjectName = EditorGUILayout.TextField("Text Field", gameObjectName);

        if (GUILayout.Button("Generate Scene")) {
            EditorSceneManager.NewScene(NewSceneSetup.DefaultGameObjects);
            EditorApplication.SaveScene();

        }
```

This code snippet runs on editor mode button. As i click the button it is making an empty scene . It prompts the window to enter scene name and save. But I want to provide name using code. Is this possible to work without popup for manual entry of the scene name? Additionally I want to open scene hirarchey gameobject to newly created empty scene(using above code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you can create the GameObjects normally, and then move then to new scene using `SceneManager.MoveGameObjectToScene`:

```
Scene newScene = EditorSceneManager.NewScene(NewSceneSetup.DefaultGameObjects);
GameObject go = new GameObject("GameObject");
SceneManager.MoveGameObjectToScene(go, newScene);
EditorApplication.SaveScene(newScene, path);
```

You can also set path on SaveScene to avoid the name prompt.

Docs: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.MoveGameObjectToScene.html

Comment: Thanks bivis but where to find newly created scene and read the full question please

Comment: The NewScene method will return the scene. You can store it to use later. I've updated my answer showing it. I see that you want to make it without name prompt, where are you putting this code?

Comment: Hi, I think that if you set path on SaveScene(), you can avoid the name prompt. Updated answer again.

Comment: Thanks Bivis but SaveScene doesn't have 2nd argument which contain path. i am using 5.3 unity.

Comment: additionally I want to add hirarchy or asset folder objects into my newly created scene but as this code run new scene becomes open and i miss the hierarchy object.

Comment: You can get objects from your asset folder, like prefabs. They need to be in Assets/Resources folder, then you can get they using `prefabObject = (GameObject)Resources.Load(prefabName, typeof(GameObject))`. You can set objects as child of the other setting `transform.parent`.